How do I remove this thermostatic mixing valve?
I need to replace the cartridge in this shower (not mixing properly) but I can't figure out how to remove it. I have no idea what brand the shower is.
I'm at the point where there appears to be a plastic nut holding in the valve, but the nut also appears to have a grub screw preventing it from turning so I don't know how to approach it. I can remove the circlip but now I'm stuck. 

